# Datatables FixedHeader sets columns to equal widths after scrolling is done

Tags: datatables, fixed-header-tables

I initialize my HTML table using the `columns` option, so that I can set the widths for each indiviual column. Initially, `fixedHeader` preserves the specified columns widths, once I start scrolling. After I scroll all the way back up, to the point that 'fixedHeaders' are deactivated (no more sticky headers), the column widths are not preserved - but they are all set to equal widths.

Anybody have an idea on how can I force the column widths to be preserved?

Comment: An issue exists for this problem on the plugin's bug tracker: https://github.com/DataTables/FixedHeader/issues/94

Answer (score 0):

You should set autoWidth option to false,as described here:[autowidth](https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth) . Then the related topics of :[columns.adjust()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()). will be helpful too.